# My tmux is no longer ordering sessions by name, how can I make it order sessions by name again when I hit <c-b> s?

Tags: tmux

[image]

I've been looking online for the longest time for an answer and couldn't find anything. Right now no matter what I name my sessions, they just remain where they are instead of ordering themselves alphabetically.

Answer (score 2):

I found a partial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891867/how-to-reorder-tmux-sessions):

> It seems sessions are being ordered by index now (i.e. the order
> they're created). You can type `O` while in session list mode to cycle
> through the different sort orderings (including `sort: name`), however I
> haven't figured out how to persist this setting.
> – Cody Aug 24 at 17:03

I would also like to know how to make this persist.

Comment: This should persist if you apply [the suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63854302/3330552) code to your `.tmux.conf` and run `source ~/.tmux.conf` to pull in the configuration updates.